# How to pass something like visitor hits from server (express.js) to next.js?

Tags: javascript, express, server, next.js

I've created a simple next.js application and provide it with a backend of express.js, now all I want is whenever someone visits the site a hit should originate on the server and the server should communicate the number of hits back to next.js application. The code of server.js file goes here:

```js
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

var counter = 0;

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });

const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.get("*", (req, res) => {
      counter++;
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(3000, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3000");
    });
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

as seen here I've set counter variable to zero and want it to be increased whenever a get request is made (so wrote counter++ inside server.get function) but how could I display this number of hits on the route visitor is visiting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use express's [`res.locals`](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.locals) in order to pass the data on the request object.

```
app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      counter++;
      res.locals.counter = counter;
      //----^
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(3000, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
    });
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Then this request object will be available in `getInitialProps` of the page that is needed.

```js
// some-page.js

const Page = ({ counter }) => <div>{counter}</div>;

Page.getInitialProps = ({ req, res }) => {
  if (res) {
    // this means that you are on the server
    return { counter: res.locals.counter };
  }

  return {};
};
```

Comment: By applying this solution I'm able to see the counts but I see the number of counts initially 2 and on reload counter increases by 10 also I've two pages on index page I displayed the counter but when I click on the link of About page and then back on index page I'm getting this error: Error: "Index.getInitialProps()" should resolve to an object. But found "undefined" instead.

Comment: In order to solve the getInitialProps error, return an empty object at the else case.
Regarding the counter, it is dependant on your implementation, currently the counter variable is a **global**, that means it is shared between users.
Apply what ever logic to it.